# Если ответ открыт из почтовой рассылки, ссылки на комментарии не раскрываются в чате

Tags: дефект, комментарии, чат, ссылки

Мне пришла почтовая рассылка — Бюллетень Stack Overflow на русском. Открыл вопрос оттуда по такой ссылке:

I've received the Stack Overflow in Russian bulletin by email and opened a question by the following link:

[Чем в C++ отличаются анонимный и безымянный классы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597439/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%bc%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b?newsletter=1&nlcode=499155%7c626e)

> `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597439/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%bc%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b?newsletter=1&nlcode=499155%7c626e`

Увидел интересный комментарий, которым хочу поделиться в чате. Вот ссылка на комментарий:

Then I've seen a comment which I'd like to share in chat. Here's the link to the comment:

[Чем в C++ отличаются анонимный и безымянный классы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597439/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%bc%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b?newsletter=1&nlcode=499155%7c626e#comment806931_597441)

> `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597439/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%bc%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b?newsletter=1&nlcode=499155%7c626e#comment806931_597441`

Теперь я публикую эту ссылку в чате. Фактическое поведение: показывается содержимое вопроса.

I publish the link in a chat message. Actual behaviour: question's content is displayed.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидаемое поведение: показывается содержимое комментария.

Expected behaviour: the comment should be displayed.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

There seem to be two problems:

1. If there are extra parameters in the page URL, they become a part of all comment links, but they shouldn't. (And if I publish such link somewhere, I disclose the `nlcode=####` part which might be bad).
2. Chat cannot parse comment links with some irrelevant parameters added.

---

For reference, a question URL without mail-related parameters.

> `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597439/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%bc%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b`

And the comment link without same parameters which you get from a normally-opened question. This is shown in chat as intended.

> `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597439/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%bc%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b#comment806931_597441`

Comment: добавь урл который ты вставлял после из письма, и тот который вставляется если по нормальному зайти, чтобы видно было чем они отличаются

Comment: @Grundy не совсем понял, какой именно я `вставлял после из письма`, но вот добавил ещё пару.

Comment: я имел ввиду ссылку на комментарий: ты добавил ссылку на комментарий, которая получается если зайти после письма. А я говорил как раз добавить ссылку на комментарий которая при обычном заходе :-)

Comment: @Grundy теперь есть обе.

Comment: ага, но что-то воспроизвести не получается :)

Comment: хотя нет, проблема в параметре: `&nlcode=499155%7c626e` причем именно с конкретным значением

Comment: даже интереснее - конкретно в символе: `%7c` - который - `|`

Comment: @Grundy ага, есть там такой символ.

Comment: похоже парсер в чате его как-то не переваривает